# ¿Cómo puedo retornar la primera coincidencia de un array de objetos de datos repetidos en JS?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un array de objetos que contiene blogs dentro

```
const blogs = [
    {
      _id: '5a422a851b54a676234d17f7',
      title: 'React patterns',
      author: 'Michael Chan',
      url: 'https://reactpatterns.com/',
      likes: 7,
      __v: 0
    }, {
      _id: '5a422aa71b54a676234d17f8',
      title: 'Go To Statement Considered Harmful',
      author: 'Edsger W. Dijkstra',
      url: 'http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html',
      likes: 5,
      __v: 0
    },
    {
      _id: '5a422b3a1b54a676234d17f9',
      title: 'Canonical string reduction',
      author: 'Edsger W. Dijkstra',
      url: 'http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD808.html',
      likes: 12,
      __v: 0
    },
    {
      _id: '5a422b891b54a676234d17fa',
      title: 'First class tests',
      author: 'Robert C. Martin',
      url: 'http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2017/05/05/TestDefinitions.htmll',
      likes: 10,
      __v: 0
    },
    {
      _id: '5a422ba71b54a676234d17fb',
      title: 'TDD harms architecture',
      author: 'Robert C. Martin',
      url: 'http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2017/03/03/TDD-Harms-Architecture.html',
      likes: 0,
      __v: 0
    },
    {
      _id: '5a422bc61b54a676234d17fc',
      title: 'Type wars',
      author: 'Robert C. Martin',
      url: 'http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2016/05/01/TypeWars.html',
      likes: 12,
      __v: 0
    }
  ];
```

Lo que deseo hacer es que me **retorne la primera coincidencia del numero mayor de likes** aun asi se repitan mucho después, por ejemplo en mi array de objetos se repiten los `likes: 12` en el index 2 y 5 por lo que lo único que deseo retornar es la primera coincidencia osea el objeto en el índice 2 del array. Toda la información de ese objeto.

Lo intenté hacer con un reduce pero me retorna la última coincidencia, más no la primera.

**Código no funcional**

```
const favoriteBlog = (blogs) => {
  
  const getFavoriteBlog = (previousValue, currentValue) => {
    return previousValue.likes > currentValue.likes ? previousValue: currentValue;
  };
  
  return blogs.reduce(getFavoriteBlog);
};
```

Comment: Podrías hacerlo con el método find:   let obj=blogs.find(o=>o.likes=== 12);

Comment: Lo que pasa es que necesito que sea dinamico ya que los blogs pueden seguir aumentandose o disminuyendose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se me ocurre una idea, ordenas los blogs de mayor a menor likes. Ahí ya sabes que el que quede en posición `0` va a ser el post que mas likes tiene o uno de los que mas tiene likes. Después solo averiguas cuantos likes tiene ese post y ya solo usas el método `find`, que te devuelve la primera coincidencia.

```
const blogs = [
  {
    _id: '5a422a851b54a676234d17f7',
    title: 'React patterns',
    author: 'Michael Chan',
    url: 'https://reactpatterns.com/',
    likes: 7,
    __v: 0
  }, {
    _id: '5a422aa71b54a676234d17f8',
    title: 'Go To Statement Considered Harmful',
    author: 'Edsger W. Dijkstra',
    url: 'http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html',
    likes: 5,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '5a422b3a1b54a676234d17f9',
    title: 'Canonical string reduction',
    author: 'Edsger W. Dijkstra',
    url: 'http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD808.html',
    likes: 12,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '5a422b891b54a676234d17fa',
    title: 'First class tests',
    author: 'Robert C. Martin',
    url: 'http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2017/05/05/TestDefinitions.htmll',
    likes: 10,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '5a422ba71b54a676234d17fb',
    title: 'TDD harms architecture',
    author: 'Robert C. Martin',
    url: 'http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2017/03/03/TDD-Harms-Architecture.html',
    likes: 0,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '5a422bc61b54a676234d17fc',
    title: 'Type wars',
    author: 'Robert C. Martin',
    url: 'http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2016/05/01/TypeWars.html',
    likes: 12,
    __v: 0
  }
];

const favoriteBlog = (blogs) => {

  let blogsSorted = blogs.sort((blog1, blog2) => blog2.likes - blog1.likes )
  let moreLikes = blogsSorted[0].likes

  return blogs.find(blog => blog.likes === moreLikes)

};

console.log(favoriteBlog(blogs))
```

RESPUESTA EDITADA ----- Se me ocurre hacer un map al array, para que sea más rápido.

```
const favoriteBlog2 = (blogList) => {
  
  let onlyLikes = blogList.map(blog => blog.likes)
  let moreLikes = Math.max.apply(null, onlyLikes)
  
  return blogList.find((mostLikedBlog) => mostLikedBlog.likes == moreLikes);
  
};

console.log(favoriteBlog2(blogs))
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta compa, funciona la solución pero en cuestión si hay más blogs (miles) la solución se tornaría algo lenta por lo que tiene que ordenar los blogs y luego encontrarlos y así si existe una cantidad sumamente alta. Gracias por tu ayuda compa.

Comment: Se me ocurre otra solución, pero la solución que marcaste como valida no es tan así, en otra respuesta te escribo como se me ocurre otra solución.

Comment: Dale compa no hay problema.

Comment: Bueno, no escribí otra respuesta, edité esta. Aunque no se me da lo de medir los rendimientos, tengo que aprender un poco de eso.

Comment: Gracias compa, funciona igual de bien que la primera respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer lo que solicitas puedes recorrer el array con un for normal o con un for in, dentro del for obtienes el valor máximo de likes de los blogs y lo almacenas en una variable, como en tus blogs tienes dos que el número de likes son 12 solo se va almacenar un 12 en dicha variable. Luego realizas el return directo de un find del blog que recibes como parámetro para que te retorne el primer objeto con el que encuentre coincidencia que sería el primer blog cuyos likes sean 12, si el primer blog llega a tener 12 retornará dicho primer blog.

```
const favoriteBlog = (blogList) => {
  let totalLikes = 0;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < blogList.length; i++) {
    
    totalLikes = Math.max(blogList[i].likes);
    
  }
  
  return blogList.find((mostLikedBlog) => mostLikedBlog.likes == totalLikes);
  
};
```

Comment: Gracias colega, funciona perfecto tu solución ante lo que requería, muchas gracias. Saludos.

Comment: Hola discrepo, esta funcion solo sirve si el ultimo blog tiene el máximo de likes, intenta poner en el ultimo blog solo 5 likes y verifica la respuesta.